# How to add function on button in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, html, dom-events, phonegap

I'm new to Phonegap and I want to develop a Phonegap application for Android.. I want to give some function on button click on my html.. I've tried this code but it does not work:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>PhoneGap</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="mycode.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init();>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="msg()" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

mycode.js

```
function init() {
    // the next line makes it impossible to see Contacts on the HTC Evo since it
    // doesn't have a scroll button
    // document.addEventListener("touchmove", preventBehavior, false);
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceInfo, true);
}

function msg()
{
    alert("button clicked");
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just put the closing "(double quotes) in the body tag

```
<body onload="init();">
```

Comment: I hate it when I do that :)